Prisma can't find postgres DB
I'm trying to launch my project using  docker compose up --build And I get error:  Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at postgres:5432 If I delete the line RUN npx prisma db push, then I can go into the docker container and execute it. And the application will work. How can I fix the error?
This is my compose.yaml file
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      PGUSER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -d $$POSTGRES_DB
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - ${POSTGRES_PORT}:5432
    networks:
      -  max-planner_network

  back:
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-back
    build:
      context: ./back
      dockerfile: ./docker/${ENV_MODE}/Dockerfile
      args:
        - BACK_PORT=${BACK_PORT}
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ./back:/project
      - /back/node_modules
    ports:
      - ${BACK_PORT}:4200
    networks:
      -  max-planner_network
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy

<-front->

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  max-planner_network:
    name: ${PROJECT_NAME}_network

This is my env file
# PROJECT ENV
ENV_MODE=dev
PROJECT_NAME=max-planner

#POSTGRES
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=planner_db

# PORTS
BACK_PORT=4200

This is my dockerfile for backend
FROM node:20.14.0

ARG BACK_PORT

WORKDIR /project

RUN npm install -g yarn -f --silent

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . ./

RUN npx prisma db push

EXPOSE ${BACK_PORT}

CMD ["yarn", "start:dev"]

I tried to transfer the command to package.json and launch it from there. But it doesn't work. I want tables to be created in the db every time docker start. For configuration dev.

You can't ever interact with your database or other containers from a Dockerfile.  (What would happen if you docker pushed the image to a registry, then docker run it again on a different machine with a clean database, without rerunning the Dockerfile?)  You need to do it manually via docker{,-compose} exec or on every startup with an entrypoint wrapper script.

Your backend service will need a .env file setting the following env var and the same variable needs to be in the docker-compose file or dockerfile since you're running npx prisma from there.
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://postgres:password@postgres:5432/plannner_db".
From Prisma docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/getting-started/setup-prisma/start-from-scratch/relational-databases/connect-your-database-typescript-postgresql
